# AttributeError : 'Settings' object has no attribute 'MERCHANT_SETTINGS'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am a newbie to Django and am following [this github link](https://github.com/agiliq/merchant/tree/master/example) to create an app for accepting payment

I am successfully able to syncdb but when I run the server at `127.0.0.1:8000` I see the following error on the web page.

```
AttributeError at /

'Settings' object has no attribute 'MERCHANT_SETTINGS'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Settings' object has no attribute 'MERCHANT_SETTINGS'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in __getattr__, line 55
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/arjun/merchant-master/example',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

I can see the `MERCHANT_SETTING` at the following path

```
merchant/example/settings/local.py-dist
```

Can someone please help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Could you try running the Django server as `./manage.py runserver 0:8000 --settings=example.settings.local.py-dist` ? The settings file pointed in manage.py is just the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add necessary MERCHANT_SETTINGS to your Django settings.py.
Here merchant [installation doc](https://django-merchant.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#configuration).

So just go to your settings.py, add your merchant settings like in this [merchant example file](https://github.com/agiliq/merchant/blob/master/example/settings/local.py-dist).

Comment: Thank you for that answer, the current issue was solved by adding MERCHANT_SETTINGS to my settings.py which is actually the common.py

Now i am facing this other issue here is the traceback for the error on the webpage.

Comment: Missing integration: fps
Exception Type: IntegrationModuleNotFound
Missing integration: fps
Exception Location: /home/arjun/merchant-master/example/billing/integration.py in get_integration, line 73


/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
        __import__(name)

/home/arjun/merchant-master/example/app/urls.py in <module>
amazon_fps_obj = get_integration("fps")

/home/arjun/merchant-master/example/billing/integration.py in get_integration raise IntegrationModuleNotFound("Missing integration: %s" % (integration))

Comment: @Muffadal seems like you need to add integration for amazon flexible payment service [(doc)](http://django-merchant.readthedocs.org/en/latest/offsite/amazon_fps.html) for this.